# Silverlight support in DotNetBrowser

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, dotnetbrowser

I tried to open website with Silverlight using DotNetBrowser and received alert that I need to install Silverlight. However, on DotNetBrowser website Silverlight is mentioned as supported.
I can open the same website in Internet Explorer without issues.

Please advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recent versions of Chromium have NPAPI disabled. Silverlight is an NPAPI plugin, so in order to use it in DotNetBrowser, you need to enable NPAPI first.

Add the code below to the constructor of the window:

```
BrowserPreferences.SetChromiumSwitches("--enable-npapi");
```